# Scrolling has stopped working in chat

Tags: bug, chat, google-chrome, scrolling

The scrolling in chat in Chrome latest (v36) doesn't work, but works for other people using the same version of Chrome. It simply: never scrolls.

Fix it fix it fix it fix it fix it fix it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This only occurs if you have the

```
chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features
```

feature flag enabled; basically, there is [some confusion over whether `body` vs `documentElement` should be the scroll-target](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=342307). Since this is an experimental flag, I'm not going to make drastic changes just yet, but will take steps if this makes it into production chrome. I have also filed a [report with jQuery.ScrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/issues/92), to make them aware of it.

Comment: I think it may have just landed in Chrome Canary. Chat hasn't been scrolling for the last two days for me now.

Comment: can reproduce on Chrome 61 (dev). enable-experimental-web-platform-features is _off_

Comment: This is making chat completely unusable at this point, let's see if we can't find the regression and either fix it or report it to chromium.